# How do I fix this error: "MyEvent += expected"?

Tags: .net, delegates

I have a delegate, say:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate();
```

I have an event, say:

```
public MyDelegate MyEvent;
```

While invoking the event I am receiving an error message:

> "MyEvent += expected ....."

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What is the code you are using to invoke this event?

Answer (score 4):

You can only invoke the event from within the class where you declared it. In any other place, you can only add or remove handlers from the event delegate via the operators `+=` and `-=`, hence the error message.

Answer (score 4):

+= is associated with events, not just a declaration of a delegate.  You are missing the 'event' keyword.

```
public **event** MyDelegate MyEvent;
```

Once you have that keyword the += will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to use the event from a different class, you need to understand the difference between events and delegates. An event just encapsulates the "subscribe" and "unsubscribe" aspects, not "raise the event". (In fact in IL you *can* have a member for "raise the event" but C# doesn't support it.)

See [my article on events and delegates](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/events.html) for more details.

Comment: I've always wondered by C# didn't support the Raise method since VB and even C++/CLI do and it's actually pretty handy sometimes. Do you know any reason for this decision?

Comment: In my opinion, it breaks encapsulation. A class should be responsible for raising events itself - the event pattern is an observational one. I've never encountered a situation where I wanted to raise an event from "outside" but had a *good* reason to do so (rather than crufty design elsewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Also you might want to take a look at this post about [avoiding checking for null delegates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c#9282)

Answer (score 0):

Check out Chris Sells [.NET Delegates: A C# Bedtime Story](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/default.aspx?content=delegates.htm) for a great guide to delegates and events. Informative and quite entertaining.